# Pricing Error & Ajax auto ON issue

Tags: magento

Magento 1.9
EDO Theme
Theres some Malicious code added in Miscellaneous Scripts on theme which puts the AJAX ON by default which has to be OFF but cannot be done off.

All my Configurable products when added to cart displays wrong pricing. ideally Total Amount = Configurable (base) price + Associated Simple product price but it shows only simple prodcuts pricing which is wrong.

Case: 
Default Configurable Product Price = 30 (Base price)
Associated Product 1KG Rice = +0 = 30 & 
Associated 2KG Price = +25 = 55

So before for 2kg it use to show proper pricing as Rs. 55 but now it shows Total as Rs. 25

This reflected to all 300 products. Please help as i am a Newbie.

Comment: The answer is in your first sentence. Update or replace the theme and remove the unwanted code. This will take research and careful planning. Keep in mind that when you use any CMS with plug-ins and themes, there is the potential of vulnerabilities. You can research known vulnerabilities here: https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search?execution=e2s1

Comment: This may help: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-15393/product_id-31613/Magento-Magento.html

Comment: http://neemafoods.com/dal-pulses.html
Can you check this Products and give some usable solution. 

In all these individual products there is a dropdown to select the the Product Weight and depending on that price changes. Here it shows proper price but It shows wrong prices when added to cart. 

In cart is shows only the Difference price (that is Actual Price - Base price )

Comment: Sorry mate! I don't know anything about Magento and AJAX. I see that Magento 1.9.something had some vulnerabilities that allowed XSS attacks and PHP files that could be uploaded. I suggest updating Magento first to hopefully close the vulnerability then see what is really required for your install/theme. I often use an old PC to make example installs to compare differences between what is on the live site and the example install. You can also check your database for entries that should not exist.

Comment: Nice looking site by the way!! I gave you an up-vote to hopefully get you some attention.